# Select a DOM element in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, render, jsx

I am relatively new in ReactJS world, I was wondering, how to select the content of h1 tag from the jsx. I tried using refs, but it turns out, it works for input forms. Is there any way we can work it out..!

```html
render(){
        return(
            <div style={{width: '100%', margin: 'auto'}}>
                <Grid className = "landing-grid">
                    <Cell col={12}>
                        <img 
                            // src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatars-15/64/_Bearded_Man-17-512.png"
                            src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatars-15/64/_Ninja-2-512.png"
                            alt = "avatar"
                            className = "avatar-img"
                            />
                        <div className="banner-text">
                            <h1>Full Stack Developer</h1>
                            <hr />
                            <p>JavaScript | React | NodeJS | Express | MongoDB | HTML/CSS | Python</p>
                            
                            <div className="social-links">
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/shamant-bhimanagoud-naik" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                                    <i className="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true" />
                                </a>

                                <a href="https://github.com/sham1516/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                                    <i className="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true" />
                                </a>

                                <a href="https://twitter.com/ShamantN" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                                    <i className="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Cell>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I wanna animate

## Full Stack Developer

. so how to select..!

Comment: What do you need the ref for? You say you "wanna animate", but there are plenty of ways to animate that don't involve refs. I ask because there's probably a simpler way to do whatever you're trying to do than mess with refs.

Comment: 1. I don't mind using other ways. Can we edit within JSX itself? 2. I might not be clear in the question I guess. I wanted the content of <h1> in a variable so that I can pass it to another function.

Comment: What will that other function do?

Comment: I am sorry, I was just trying some random methods to select. I am not thorough with React concepts.

Comment: It is almost certain that you do not need a ref. My goal is to help you rewrite that other function so that it does things the "react way", but i can't do that if i don't know what the function does.

Comment: If you want to animate the text, you can probably use css selector of say `.banner-text > h1` or something like that that doesn't involve using refs at all

Comment: the function will display the characters of <h1> tag in a small-time interval, which is done in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUEB9FogoP8&t=321s

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a ref for this. You just need to set component state, and use that state in your render method. In this case, the state is just a single number indicating how far into the string we've gotten so far, and the render method needs to create a bunch of spans, and set the class on some of them.

Heres how it might look extracted to a reusable component:

```
class Fancy extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prev => ({ index: prev.index + 1 }));
    }, 50);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.index >= this.props.text.length) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  render () {
    const spans = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.text.length; i++) {
      spans.push((
        <span key={i} className={i < this.state.index ? 'fade' : undefined}>
          {this.props.text[i]}
        </span>
      ));
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {spans}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

To be used like:

```
<div className="banner-text">
  <h1><Fancy text="Full Stack Developer" /></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to select the DOM node, you can use `document.querySelector()`. Here's the MSDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: While that function can indeed get a dom node, it's not the right approach in a react application.

Comment: It has its uses but you're right. That's why I specifically asked if that's what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can import "react-dom" and create a variable like so:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
...
someMethod() {
const dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
//here you can use usual DOM methods like querySelector() on the dom variable
}
...
```